# Why is my foreach() loops returning files into my current directory?

Tags: php, foreach, directory-structure

Originally, I had separated my cf_replace() and the inner foreach() loop in another .php file.  When I ran my script.php that called that code, it was fine.  Now that I have to combine my two php scripts into one, somehow, one of my foreach() loops is not keeping the cf_replace function within the directory and is, instead, spitting out empty files into my current directory!  I've been staring at this code for a while and would appreciate a fresh set of eyes.

```
$ip = $argv[1];

// Declare vars - e.g. $currentTime     
    $htmlDir = "app/HtmlPages/$ip" ."-". "$currentTime/$ip/index.php/art";
    ...
    // Make the directory where the generated HTML files will go.
    mkdir( "app/HtmlPages/$ip" ."-". "$currentTime", 0777, false );


    // Use wget to recurse over the entire website, downloading every webpage.
    $wget_cmd = "wget -P app/HtmlPages/$ip"."-"."$currentTime/ \
        --recursive \
        --no-clobber \
        --domains $ip \
            http://$ip/index.php/art/art.htm";
exec ( $wget_cmd );
...
// Iterate through each Html file in $htmlDir and replace with ColdFusion
foreach( new DirectoryIterator( $htmlDir ) as $htm_file)
{
    if( $htm_file->isDot () || !$htm_file->isFile ()) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach( new DirectoryIterator ( './cf_templates/' ) as $cf_file ) 
    {
        // Checks for all files
        if ($cf_file->isDot () || ! $cf_file->isFile ()) {
            continue;
    }

        // Grabs the template name and content to replace
        $cf_name = $cf_file->getBasename( $cf_file->getExtension() );
        $cf_code = file_get_contents( './cf_templates/' . $cf_file );

        cf_replace( $cf_name, $cf_code, $htm_file );

    }

    echo "Finished replacing Html code in $htm_file.\r\n";

}
...

function cf_replace( $name, $new_code, $source ) {
    $content = file_get_contents( $source );

    $start = preg_quote( "<!-- $name COLDFUSION BEGIN -->" , "#");
    $end = preg_quote( "<!-- $name COLDFUSION END -->", "#" );

    $needle_search = '#( $start )(.*?)( $end )#si';
    $temp = preg_replace( $needle_search, $new_code, $content );
    $temp = file_put_contents( $source, $temp );

    return $temp;
}
```

I would think that the file_put_contents() in cf_replace() would just put the files back into the original file - which is kept in the same directory...no?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, the error message I would usually get is:
`PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(test1.htm): failed to open stream:`
and 
`Warning: file_put_contents(app/HtmlPages/server.com-2015_11_20_11:25:33/server.com/index.php/art)`

Comment: `DirectoryIterator` just returns the filenames, they don't include the directory prefix. You need to include the directory when you try to access the files.

Comment: also `DirectoryIterator ( './cf_templates/' )` is going to be relative to your current working directory, not the directory of `$htm_file` or `$htmlDir` unless you specifically change directory in your script.

Comment: I wanted to change directories so that 'for each htm_file in the $htmlDir, replace the specified code by running it against each cf_file found in './cf-templates' '.  I would think that would work?? I could be mistaken.

Comment: Thank you all for the insight.  @Barmar: I'm a little confused; could you please elaborate?  If I try `foreach( $htmlDir as $html_file ) {... }` , the system gives me a message that there is an "invalid argument supplied for foreach()", so I can't tell if it will even loop correctly.  I also tried to put a scandir() variable into the first foreach(), but that was erroring on that it couldn't be opened; not a file or directory...

Comment: If should be `foreach (new DirectoryIterator($htmlDir) as $html_file)`, like you wrote in the question.

Comment: The file you want to access is `$htmlDir/$html_file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names returned when you loop over the directory iterator don't contain the directory name. You need to add that, so call

```
cf_replace($name, $cf_code, "$htmlDir/$htmFile");
```

Comment: Thank you, Barmar, for both a solution and explanation.  That solved the issue!